# Can't sort a MongoDB database using mongoose in a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, sorting, asynchronous, mongoose, promise

I am by no means a developer! Nevertheless, I'm trying to put together a demo app for my startup.

I'm having a lot of trouble (days and days) trying to sort results from a mongoose "find". I've looked extensively for an answer, but have found that work. Here's a code snippet that does NOT work:

```
const warehouses = require("../models/warehousesModel.js");

merchantWarehouseQuotes = (req, res) => {
    let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(warehouses.find({location: req.body.location}).exec());
    });
    p.then((localWarehouses) => {
        let sortMethod = req.body.warehouseSorting;
        localWarehouses.forEach(s => {
            if (sortMethod == "price") {
                s.sortingMetric = s.pricePerCubicFoot;
            } else {
                s.sortingMetric = -s.metrics;
            };
            s.save();
        });

        return localWarehouses.sort({sortingMetric: 1}).exec();
    })
    .then((localWarehouses) => {
        console.log(localWarehouses);
    });
};
```

The app crashes on the sort that I attempt on the 5th from the last line of code.

Maddeningly, the following code runs fine. The only problem is that it performs the sort BEFORE I've defined the sorting metric, which is useless to me.

```
merchantWarehouseQuotes = (req, res) => {
    let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(warehouses.find({location: req.body.location}).sort({sortingMetric: 1}).exec());
    });
    p.then((localWarehouses) => {
        console.log(localWarehouses)
        let sortMethod = req.body.warehouseSorting;
        localWarehouses.forEach(s => {
            if (sortMethod == "price") {
                s.sortingMetric = s.pricePerCubicFoot;
            } else {
                s.sortingMetric = -s.metrics;
            };
            s.save();
        });

        return localWarehouses;
    })
    .then((localWarehouses) => {
        console.log(localWarehouses);

    });
};
```

Here the sort happens on the second line from the top. But, like I said, that does not use the appropriate metric for the sort.

Finally, I've tried all kinds of variations to the code to get it to work. The first snippet (which does not work) is just one example of the problems I'm having!

Answer (score 0):

After more headbanging, I think I've resolved my problem. The following code, which explicitly provides a sorting method, seems to work!

```
localWarehouses.sort(function(a,b) {
                if (a.sortingMetric > b.sortingMetric) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (a.sortingMetric < b.sortingMetric) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            })
```